# Scaling the System and its Database for 10k request handling. What's right Sharding or Microservice going for Distributed database

Tags: mysql, microservices, scaling, distributed-database

"Inability of MySQL to scale write requests beyond one node became a killer problem as data volumes grew leaps and bounds. MySQL’s monolithic architecture essentially forces application-level sharding.The development and operational complexity grows exponentially when the number of such instances grow from 1 to 100s and thereafter explode into 1000s."

So, If I use sharding for scaling up the application then

1. I cannot use the database itself for any cross-shard JOINs and transactions. It seems true but  **it Is it True** ??
2. What's the better and efficient way to scaling the application as well as the database for say 10k concurrent requests and more. ?? 
   I think going for microservices is not the solution here or is it ??

Comment: I can wait to see many answers to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The answer is more nuanced than simply true or false. A horizontal
   sharding solution for MySQL like **Vitess** ([vitess.io](https://vitess.io)) does allow you
   to do both [cross-shard joins](https://vitess.io/docs/reference/mysql-compatibility/#join-queries) and [transactions](https://vitess.io/docs/reference/features/two-phase-commit/), but *just because you
   can doesn’t mean you should*. A sharded architecture will perform
   best if you design it well and play to its strength, e.g. favoring
   single-shard targeted writes within any individual transaction.
   Enabling two-phase commit in Vitess to support cross-shard writes *is*
   possible, but will come at a significant performance cost. Whether that tradeoff is worth it differs from application to application, and generally speaking, adjusting the schema/workload is considered the better approach.
2. It’s better to think of microservices as a design principle than as
   a scaling trick. This architecture is more tailored to improving
   resilience and flexibility of deployment, by breaking up monolithic
   deployments into more loosely coupled, isolated elements. Because
   the complexity of managing resources for horizontal sharding align
   closely with the challenges of managing resources in a microservices
   architecture, Vitess is actually a great fit for a container
   orchestration environment and is commonly deployed/managed in
   containers using the Vitess Operator for Kubernetes.

In short, horizontally scaling MySQL is both feasible and commonly done, both in microservices architectures, as well as more traditional environments.

As an aside, 10K concurrent requests is relatively vague measure. It’s not abnormal for a well-configured single-server MySQL installation to serve hundreds of thousands of queries per second, so keep in mind that any scaling challenges you might face could also be resolved by optimizing your code, queries, schema and/or MySQL configuration.

Comment: "It’s better to think of microservices as a design principle than as a scaling trick." 
Was not the concept of Microservice introduced for scaling things up, or am I wrong here ??

Comment: The primary benefit to microservices architectures is the fact that components of an application can be isolated and dealt with individually. Performance factors into this, but think back to the good old days when a poorly configured MySQL could "oom kill" the web server living on the same machine. Isolation of services allows them all to be given a space that is optimized for them and allows for CI/CD processes to target only the components needed. Performance is not held back by this, but it's not the driver.